# How to combine TextView, a button, and a ListView on Mono Android (C#)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, listview, xamarin.android

I'm trying to take user input from a TextView, this can be part of someone's name. And a button to + delegate an event, and then display a list of matching entries with phone numbers in a ListView. From the tutorials I have seen, Android either displays a ListView using : ListActivity with separate xml, which would not display the TextView and the button, or using : Activity with Main.axml, which would not let me populate the ListView with something like this: 
ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.list_item, phone_list);

 where list_item is a separate xml file from Main.axml. If I use Main, it would give me a runtime error

Answer (score 0):

main.xml should contain the main layout for your `Activity`, which would include a `ListView`. In your `Activity`, you grab the `ListView` and set the adapter to whatever adapter you provide. In a separate xml file, define the row for each list item.